# Dollarsign tags are not working, how do i fix this

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am making a discord bot and the tags like `${message.guild.name}` does not work, how do I fix this

I have followed the guide, and it did not give any detailed information,

```
} else if (message.content === '${prefix}beep') {
    message.channel.send('Boop!')
} else if (message.content === '${prefix}serverinfo') {
message.channel.send('The name of the server is: ${message.guild.name}');
}
```

I expect it to do this: to type `/serverinfo` and it responds with `The name of the server is: Gaming For Everyone`

If I type `/serverinfo` it does not respond and you need to type in `${prefix}serverinfo` to get a response and it answers with: `The name of the server is: ${message.guild.name}`

Comment: You are using single quotes ('). You need to use the tick (`) (on left of 1 on the keyboard)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is due to the use of single quotes (`'`). In order to use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (`${var}`), back ticks/grave accents must be used (`` ` ``).

Example:

```js
let prefix = "sound";
console.log(`${prefix} beep`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with  ( ` ) instead of (') like

```
 `${prefix}beep`
```

Because it should be this sign (`)